# How to read some part of an xml, and update to the actual xml file

Tags: java, jaxb

I want to modify jmeter script which is an xml file via java application. so it has large amount of properties that could be configured but I only want to modify some parts of it.

I use JAXB and I created a model that only map 1 property that i'm interested which is `variableThroughputTimer`.

```
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name = "hashTree")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class JmeterConfig {

    @XmlElement(name = "kg.apc.jmeter.timers.VariableThroughputTimer")
    private VariableThroughputTimer variableThroughputTimer;

}
```

the actual xml file

```
<hashTree>
    <kg.apc.jmeter.timers.VariableThroughputTimer guiclass="kg.apc.jmeter.timers.VariableThroughputTimerGui" testclass="kg.apc.jmeter.timers.VariableThroughputTimer" testname="throughput-shaping-timer-1" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="load_profile">
            <collectionProp name="912502873">
                <stringProp name="1">1</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="1512450">10</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="-1887941201">10</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
            <collectionProp name="311615172">
                <stringProp name="1512450">10</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="1512450">10</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="78419694">10</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
            <collectionProp name="-2065473974">
                <stringProp name="1512450">10</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="49">1</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="1722">60</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
        </collectionProp>
    </kg.apc.jmeter.timers.VariableThroughputTimer>
    <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="1. test something" enabled="true">
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.postBodyRaw">true</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/some-api</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">POST</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
    </HTTPSamplerProxy>
</hashTree>
```

Eveything works fine until I saved the file back to the xml. Now since it doesnt have `HTTPSamplerProxy` property so it writes the file with `VariableThroughputTimer` only.

The result

```
<hashTree>
    <kg.apc.jmeter.timers.VariableThroughputTimer guiclass="kg.apc.jmeter.timers.VariableThroughputTimerGui" testclass="kg.apc.jmeter.timers.VariableThroughputTimer" testname="throughput-shaping-timer-1" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="load_profile">
            <collectionProp name="912502873">
                <stringProp name="1">1</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="1512450">10</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="-1887941201">10</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
            <collectionProp name="311615172">
                <stringProp name="1512450">10</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="1512450">10</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="78419694">10</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
            <collectionProp name="-2065473974">
                <stringProp name="1512450">10</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="49">1</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="1722">60</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
        </collectionProp>
    </kg.apc.jmeter.timers.VariableThroughputTimer>
</hashTree>
```

so is it possible to read some part of an xml file, modify it and save it back without touching the existing property. one solution that I can think of is to create a model that cover the whole properties of xml file but that's a lot of work to do.

this is my service for reading and writing xml.

```
@Component
public class JmeterConfigurationConverter {
    public JmeterConfig read() throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(JmeterConfig.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:sample.xml");
        return (JmeterConfig) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
    }

    public void save(JmeterConfig jmeterConfig) throws JAXBException, IOException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(JmeterConfig.class);
        Marshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:sample.xml");
        FileOutputStream opt = new FileOutputStream(file);
        jaxbUnmarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        jaxbUnmarshaller.marshal(jmeterConfig, opt);
        opt.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: "create a model that cover the whole properties of xml file" - that would be your best bet. One other alternative if it's only minor changes could be to use the DOM parser in Java. [How to modify XML file in Java – DOM Parser](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) shows an example of how this can be used.